# Schwarz Lemma in Differential Form

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose $w=f(z)$ is a conformal self map of $\mathbb{D}$.

From Schwarz Pick Lemma
we have $|\frac{dw}{dz}|=\frac{1-|w|^2}{1-|z|^2}$.

Could any one explain me In differential form how this becomes $\frac{|dw|}{1-|w|^2}=\frac{|dz|}{1-|z|^2}$

Comment: I assume you're looking for something more than "multiply by $|dz|$ and divide by $1-|w|^2$"? How rigorous do you want it? What is your definition of $|dz|$ and $|dw|$?

Comment: Thank you, I was just reading it from Gamelin's Book, page-266, before that he did picks , but he did not defined |dz| and |dw|. so I would be happy if you make it as rigorious as possible, I have knowledge of Differential Geometry for one semester course, differential forms, etc etc and complex analysis also, but not any knowledge of Hyperbolc geometry which I was just starting